# Making msg.sender available for external contract

Tags: interface, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to make a function that harvest all rewards from a dAPP.

- Contract to harvest:

```
function harvest(uint256 pid,address to)...{
     UserInfo storage user = userInfo[pid][msg.sender];
     .............
     token.safeTransfer(to, value)
}
```

- MyContractToHarvestAll:

```
function myFunction(address _user) ...{
.....
for(i < maxPid){
   IMasterchef(masterchef).harvest(i, _user); 
}
....
}
```

As you can see whenever I call .harvest() function it checks for msg.sender that in my case is MyContractToHarvestAll. This is an error because the harvest() function will never find any information about the real msg.sender (the caller of MyContractToHarvestAll).

If I try:

```
 contract.delegateCall(abi...(harvest...))
```

it doesn't work because of storage context

---

My questions are:

- there is a possibilty to make a delegateCall using interfaces? Something like that:

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) = IMasterchef(masterchef).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("harvest(uint256,address)",i,_user));
```

- Do you know any tips to make msg.sender = the caller of MyContractHarvestAll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *there is a possibilty to make a delegateCall using interfaces*

Currently (v0.8) not possible on an interface. You'll need to use the (low-level) `delegatecall` member of the `address` type

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) =  masterchef.delegatecall(
    abi.encodeWithSignature("harvest(uint256,address)", i, _user)
);
```

> *Do you know any tips to make msg.sender = the caller of MyContractHarvestAll?*

By using the `delegatecall`. But then the EVM uses storage of the proxy (`MyContractToHarvestAll`) - not of the target (`Contract to harvest`).

It's not possible by design to have the original caller as `msg.sender` passed through a proxy, and to use the storage of the target at the same time.

*Note: The original caller is stored in the deprecated `tx.origin` global variable. But unless you are able to modify the `Contract to harvest` (to use `tx.origin` instead of `msg.sender`), there's no way to bypass this logic.*

Comment: Yeah as I thought. At this point I'll use web3 and not a contract in solidity :( 
Thank you, appreciated!